# The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am loading some data via WCF on the loading of a given page. I then want to populate a Picker with the values once the data has loaded. However, I'm getting a cross threading problem. Here is the code:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await Initialise(); });
}

private async Task Initialise()
{
    var activities = await App.XivicServicesClient.DataAccessCalls.GetRecordsAsync<ActivityDef>(null, new ConnectionInfo(null, App.XivicServicesClient.AuthToken));

    var activityCodes = activities.Select(a => a.Code);
    foreach (var activityCode in activityCodes)
    {
        ActivityPicker.Items.Add(activityCode);
    }
}
```

In Windows UWP, the error I get is

*Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))*

I guess that I am using the OnAppearing call in an unintended way, so how should I get around this? I need to make a Task Based Async WCF call when the page starts loading.

On iOS, I don't get the error.

Comment: As noted, you shouldn't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` here. What's more, `Task.Factory.StartNew` is a dangerous method; even if you *want* to run code on a background thread, it should almost never be used (use `Task.Run` instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple. I'd added code that wasn't necessary, and that code was causing the bug. Here is the fixed method:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await Initialise();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem comes from

```
ActivityPicker.Item.Add(activityCode);
```

That line may ONLY be run on the UI thread.

You can easily fix this code with the following

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var activityCodes = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => { await Initialise(); });

    foreach (var activityCode in activityCodes)
    {
        ActivityPicker.Items.Add(activityCode);
    }
}

private async Task<List<string>> Initialise()
{
    var activities = await App.XivicServicesClient
                       .DataAccessCalls
                       .GetRecordsAsync<ActivityDef>(null, new ConnectionInfo(null, App.XivicServicesClient.AuthToken));

    return activities.Select(a => a.Code).ToList();

}
```

However, I really doubt that you "need" to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`. `GetRecordsAsync` already is an async method. Chances are, most of the delay in `Initialise`(sic) comes from the I/O latency.

Running `Initialise` from another thread will only INCREASE the run time, as the data needs to be marshaled across threads, along with synchronization.

Rather, try.

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    var activities = await App.XivicServicesClient
                          .DataAccessCalls
                          .GetRecordsAsync<ActivityDef>(null, new ConnectionInfo(null, App.XivicServicesClient.AuthToken));

    foreach (var activityCode in activities.Select(a => a.Code))
    {
        ActivityPicker.Items.Add(activityCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of great information here. You've given a good explanation for something that I figured out from trial and error.